# Difference between validate and validateSync in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm looking at mongoose doc, but not clear enough about validate() and validateSync(), i want to know difference between these 2 methods.

Answer (score 2):

validate() returns a promise of void. So you can't hold the result on a variable like this

```
const result = await course.validate() // can't hold
```

to handle the validation error you may need to use validate method with a callback.

```
course.validate((err) => {
   if (err) handleError(err);
   else // validation passed
})
```

on the other hand validateSync() Executes registered validation rules (skipping asynchronous validators) for this document.
It returns ValidationError if there are errors during validation, or undefined if there is no error.

```
const err = course.validateSync();
if (err) {
  handleError(err);
} else {
  // validation passed
}
```

***Note: This method is useful if you need synchronous validation.